# Algorithm for computing the largest number of subsegments

Tags: algorithm

Given a vector of n integer-valued segments, I'm searching for an O(n log n) algorithm to compute the segment which contains the most of other segments.
In fact I'm only interested in the number of those segments.

I've tried variations of segment tree and interval tree, but none where relevant. The real issue I have comes from the partial order. If the order was total, the problem would be much easier by computing directly the inclusion tree.

Example : `a = [4;11] b = [2;7] c = [5;8] d = [6;7] e = [3;9] f = [1;10] g = [10;42]`

Here we have f which contains e c b and d which is maximal. Of course, g is much longer but does not contain any of the other segments, so it's not a matter of the largest segment.

We can display the order graph (transitive arcs are not shown) :

```
f -----> b  ---> d
  \-->e--->c-/
       a-/
g
```

The main problem for me is that I can't exclude a while treating segments, because at some point subsegments can appear which are not included in f and make a the largest segment.

Comment: Can your sub-segments have sub-segments? That is, can this have several levels?

Comment: If you have a University library near by try in here: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Foundations-Multidimensional-Structures-Kaufmann-Computer/dp/0123694469

Comment: Edited description to add an example.

Comment: How do you define inclusion?  Why is `[4;11]` considered to be included in `[1;10]`, but `[10;42]` isn't included in `[4;11]`?

Comment: oops it's an error [4;11] is not included in [1;10]

Comment: Are you sure about the equivalence of the graph depth and the number of the segments contained within the "largest" one? [1,20] contains four segments: [1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8] but the depth of the graph is only 1. Which number do you want in this case?

Comment: You are right. The real number I'm searching for is the cardinal of the largest star subgraph of the order graph. I don't know if there's a name for this.

Comment: The O(n*n) is the lowest time complexity on this one. I thought I found a solution, but (just like you also stated) I realized that the order of the segments makes it necessary to evaluate inclusion of all other segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a direct solution in O(n log n).

Sort the segments using lexicographic order first in increasing order of x coordinate and after on decreasing order of y coordinate. Given this order if a segment (a,b) > (a',b') we are guaranteed that either a > a' or a=a' but b < b'. Either way, (a,b) can't contain (a',b').
The number of remaining segments is n minus the index of segment k in this sorted array. Let's note Sk those segments.

Of those segments, we can use the opposite order (decreasing y then increasing x) and the index of segment k amounts to the number of segments in Sk which are not included in segment k.

The trick here is that counting directly included segments is hard, but counting included segments + non include segments on the left (or on the right) is easy.

To sum up in pseudo-code :

```
segments as triples (low,high,id)
orderedXY = sort segments first inc. x then dec. y then inc. id
orderedYX = sort segments first dec. y then inc. x then inc. id
return max(n - orderedXY.find(id=k) - orderedYX.find(id=k) - 1, for every id k)
```

This algorithm is O(n log n) because of the two sorts.

EDIT : To handle duplicated segments we have to sort on a third key (the id of the segment). This way the sort is stable.

EDIT' : To be sure to count each segment only once, we need to substract 1.

Comment: Excellent solution. I had found the relationship, but was still looking at why it actually worked. It is indeed easier to reason from excluded segments. I think that you count each segment as including itself and that you need to subtract 1. A negative number means an interval is double-counted, and thus it is the number of intervals something is included in.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I need to substract 1. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

O(n log n) is possible (I am assuming open intervals and no endpoints overlap)

You sort all the end points into a sorted list (ascending), and keep a track of which interval(say using an id) and which end of an interval a particular point was.

Now you maintain a data-structure which supports the following:

```
AppendAtEnd(interval_id)
int GetPosition(interval_id)
Value Remove(interval_id)
IncrementValuesLessThanPosition(j)
```

This is a structure which takes a key (intervals_ids) and maintains an ordered (by insertion time) list of them, with an additional value, which is initially 0, which we use to keep track of the sub-intervals.

It allows you to insert at the end. Remove using the id (and get the corresponding value), get the position of the id (think of it like the distance from the head if it were implemented using a linked list) and increment all the values of a particular prefix of the list.

To use this structure for our problem, we walk the above sorted list, and each time we see the left end point of an interval, we call AppendAtEnd.

Each time we see the right end point of an interval, we get its position, we remove it, and increment all the values less than that position (basically all the intervals that have this removed interval as a sub-interval).

Using balanced trees with appropriate decorated info (like sub-tree sums and node counts), this is doable so that each operation is O(log n).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I've found a solution using plain arrays.